# Adding a Textbox destroys Menu-Layout

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, google-chrome

I'm working on a little project with ASP and C#.

In my project I'm using a masterpage for the navigationbar on the top of my pages, looking like that:

[image]

The navigationbar contains some normal navigation-points and one to log out with `float: right;`

On all of my diffenrent pages this works excepted for one.
The only difference is, that on this special page I have some textbox-elements like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbTOP1sum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

As soon as  I only enter one of this textboxes my navigationbar looks like that:

[image]

It  doesn't matter what sort of element im adding, everything is okay, excepted with this textboxes.

I noticed that this only happens in Google-chrome, not with Firefox and not with Internet-Explorer or Edge. Another thing i found out is, that disabling and enabling the CSS-rule in Chrome-Page-Inspector fixes the problem.

I have no idea what to do...
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally turned out, that adding `display: inline;` to the  of the navigationbars `<ul>` is all to do.

Another way is to do it with table columns. One for the normal content and one for the logout.

Thanks for the other answers!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue sometimes. When you change it in the inspector go into your code and make the same change and save/build, go to the web browser and do a hard refresh with "ctrl+F5". If it still does not work, wrap your logout a link in a div and then call it in CSS. Set the position to relative, and then put the top: -55px;

Comment: I tried this one, but no result still looking the same way... any other idea?